# Writing multiple files from websites in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_csv('env_sequences.csv')

Namedf = df['Name']
Uniprotdf = df['ID']



for row in Uniprotdf:

    theurl = 'https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/' + row + '.fasta'
    page = requests.get(theurl).content



    for row in Namedf:
        fasta = open(row + '.txt', 'w')
        fasta.write(page)
        fasta.close()

#Sample website: https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04578.fasta
```

I have a .csv file, from which I am using the column 'ID' to generate links to websites from which I want to download the content and save it as the corresponding name from the 'Name' column within the same .csv.

The code ceases to work after  the second for loop in which I get a TypeError for trying to use the page variable within the fasta.write() function. Yet, If I print(page) I am able to output the text that I'm looking to have in each file. Is this a case of me having to convert html into a string? I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Can you post the URL for the row that has the problem?

Comment: None of the URLs are a problem, they all seem to work. The second for loop where I am trying to write the content of the page to a .txt file is what doesn't seem to work. I'll attach a link to the .csv from which I am working from which could help better understand what I mean. 
https://uploadfiles.io/tmi58td3

Comment: variable name of both the loops are same `row`. Change that.

Comment: Thanks - although I was still curious to have a look at that particular URL as there may be something in the response that causes the write operation to fail.

Comment: The URL should be no more different to the one I included in the post (https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04578.fasta). All of the URLs I am trying to access just have a different string before the .fasta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given [url](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04578.fasta), if you print the content of the page, you'll notice that it has '***`b'`***' which indicates it's in `binary` format.

```
 print (page)
b'>sp|P04578|ENV_HV1H2 Envelope glycoprotein gp160 OS=Human immunodeficiency virus type 1 group M subtype B (isolate HXB2) OX=11706 GN=env PE=1 SV=2\nMRVKEKYQHLWRWGWRWGTMLLGMLMICSATEKLWVTVYYGVPVWKEATTTLFCASDAKA\nYDTEVHNVWATHACVPTDPNPQEVVLVNVTENFNMWKNDMVEQMHEDIISLWDQSLKPCV\nKLTPLCVSLKCTDLKNDTNTNSSSGRMIMEKGEIKNCSFNISTSIRGKVQKEYAFFYKLD\nIIPIDNDTTSYKLTSCNTSVITQACPKVSFEPIPIHYCAPAGFAILKCNNKTFNGTGPCT\nNVSTVQCTHGIRPVVSTQLLLNGSLAEEEVVIRSVNFTDNAKTIIVQLNTSVEINCTRPN\nNNTRKRIRIQRGPGRAFVTIGKIGNMRQAHCNISRAKWNNTLKQIASKLREQFGNNKTII\nFKQSSGGDPEIVTHSFNCGGEFFYCNSTQLFNSTWFNSTWSTEGSNNTEGSDTITLPCRI\nKQIINMWQKVGKAMYAPPISGQIRCSSNITGLLLTRDGGNSNNESEIFRPGGGDMRDNWR\nSELYKYKVVKIEPLGVAPTKAKRRVVQREKRAVGIGALFLGFLGAAGSTMGAASMTLTVQ\nARQLLSGIVQQQNNLLRAIEAQQHLLQLTVWGIKQLQARILAVERYLKDQQLLGIWGCSG\nKLICTTAVPWNASWSNKSLEQIWNHTTWMEWDREINNYTSLIHSLIEESQNQQEKNEQEL\nLELDKWASLWNWFNITNWLWYIKLFIMIVGGLVGLRIVFAVLSIVNRVRQGYSPLSFQTH\nLPTPRGPDRPEGIEEEGGERDRDRSIRLVNGSLALIWDDLRSLCLFSYHRLRDLLLIVTR\nIVELLGRRGWEALKYWWNLLQYWSQELKNSAVSLLNATAIAVAEGTDRVIEVVQGACRAI\nRHIPRRIRQGLERILL\n'
```

Changing the '`w`' to '`wb`' while opening the file should fix it. Also, using `with open ()` is the more pythonic way of handling files.

```
for row in Namedf:
    with open ('url.txt','wb') as fasta:
        file.write(page)
```